# how to loop through time values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, time

I have a situation where user pick start, end time and meeting length. Once start time is selected and meeting length I have to loop from START time all the way until 5:00PM with increment of meeting length and output each time slot in END time. I have my code working with Date API in javascript, problem is that my for loop gives me just first value and then stop. I'm not sure what is odd in my code so if anyone can help please let me know. Here is my code:

```
<tr>
  <th>Start Time:</th>
  <td>
    <select name="stime" id="stime" />
                <option value="">--Select start time--</option>
        </select>
  </td>
  <br />

  <th>Meeting Length:</th>
  <td>
    <select name="meet_leng" id="meet_leng">
            <option value="">--Select length--</option>
        </select>
  </td>
  <br />

  <th>End Time:</th>
  <td>
    <select name="etime" id="etime"/>
            <option value="">--Select end time--</option>
        </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    //This loop create values fro meeting length
    for(var i=5; i <= 60; i+=5){
        $('#meet_leng').append('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+' min'+'</option>')
    }


    for(var i=700; i<= 1700; i+=15){
    var mins = i % 100;
    var hours = parseInt(i/100);

    if (mins > 45) {
        mins = 0;
      hours += 1;
      i = hours * 100;
    }

    var AmPm = " AM";
    //var standardTime = hours > 11 ? ' PM' : ' AM';
    //format hours
    if(hours == 12){
        AmPm = " PM";
    }

        if (hours > 12) {
        hours = hours - 12;
        AmPm = " PM";
        }

    $('#stime').append('<option value="'+('0' + (hours)).slice(-2)+':'+('0' + mins).slice(-2)+AmPm+'">'+('0' + (hours)).slice(-2)+':'+('0' + mins).slice(-2)+AmPm+' </option>')
  }
});

$('#meet_leng').on('change', function() {
    var time1 = new Date();
  var time2 = new Date();
  var add = new Date();

  //meeting length
  var meetingLength = parseInt($('#meet_leng').val());

    //start time 
  var startTime = $('#stime').val();
    var startHour = startTime.split(':')[0];
  var startMin = startTime.split(':')[1].replace(/AM|PM/gi,'');

  //end time
  var endTime = '05:00 PM';
  var endHour = endTime.split(':')[0];
  var endMin = endTime.split(':')[1].replace(/AM|PM/gi,'');

  //Check if start time is PM and adjust hours to military
    if(startTime.indexOf('PM') > -1){
    startHour = parseInt(startHour) + 12;
    console.log(startHour);
    alert(startHour)
  }

  //Check if end time is PM and adjust hours to military
  if(endTime.indexOf('PM') > -1){
    endHour = parseInt(endHour) + 12;
    console.log(endHour);
  }

  //Date API start time
  time1.setHours(parseInt(startHour));
    time1.setMinutes(parseInt(startMin));

  //Date API end time
  time2.setHours(parseInt(endHour));
    time2.setMinutes(parseInt(endMin));

  //Adding meeting length to start time, this value will be use for end    time
  time1.setMinutes(time1.getMinutes() + meetingLength);

  for(var i=time1; i <= time2; i+=meetingLength){
    $('#etime').append('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>')
  }

});
```

Here is working example of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/dmilos89/6n458ze9/6/.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the first two dropdowns have different values and the third dropdown has no values but does have a value when you select a start time?

Comment: The meeting length loop seems to work in the JSFiddle using Google Chrome.

Comment: If I pick 7:00am start time, meeting length 15min for example, I should get values in my end drop down like this 7:15am, 7:30am, 7:45am,... 5:00pm. But my current code gives me just 7:15am. Also I update my jsfiddle.

Comment: why are you changing the value of your loop variable inside your loop ( i = hours * 100)?

Comment: To get my hours to military time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you replace your for loop with this you will get all the time that end before 17:00

```
do {
        time1.setMinutes(time1.getMinutes() + meetingLength);
        $('#etime').append('<option value="' + time1 + '">' + time1 + '</option>');
      } while (time1 < time2)
```

or

```
time1.setMinutes(time1.getMinutes() + meetingLength);

while (time1 < time2){
    $('#etime').append('<option value="' + time1 + '">' + time1 + '</option>');
    time1.setMinutes(time1.getMinutes() + meetingLength);
{
```

either is valid but the second one will also filter out any meeting that will instantly over run 17:00

the += in the for loop just adds the meeting length to the end of the string representation.

Comment: Martin this works! Thank you so much. Can you please explain one more time why for loop did not work in this case and why I have to use DO or WHILE?

Comment: Does this really works? Try setting start time to 3:45 PM and a meeting length of 55 minutes

Comment: @phenxd hence why i added the while loop version to increment it first then start looping.

Comment: Both versions do not add the first value. start time : 7am, lenght 5min -> ending at 7:05 is missing. Also you should remove old options when new ones are selected. Edit and I'll upvote

Comment: That's right actually. I got all values just when I selected 7:00am. If I select any other start time with increment I get just one value in end dropdwon. Do you know why? @MartinGlennon

Comment: Oh I think all is good afterall, I had this this twice : time1.setMinutes(time1.getMinutes() + meetingLength);

Comment: so which code actually works? @phenxd can anyone update jsfiddle please ?

Comment: here you go https://jsfiddle.net/vsamvsoh/1/

it's based on the code in this question not what is on your fiddler link

Comment: How we can clear END time drop down if I select different start time or meeting length? Thanks for working example. I was missing adding part twice.  @MartinGlennon

Comment: add a class to each of the options you append and then you can call `$('.<classname>').remove();` as the first action in the change handler

Comment: $('#etime').find('option:gt(0)').remove(); at the beginning of on-change

Comment: What should be changed in the code in order to get time slots after for loop like this for example: 7:00 am - 7:15 am, 7:15 am - 7:30am ,.... ?

Comment: you need to update the option to `'<option value="' + time.getHours() + ':' +  + time1.getMinutes() '">' + time.getHours() + ':' +  + time1.getMinutes() + '</option>'`

Comment: Thanks @MartinGlennon